# can we add more than 2 ranges for Google Analytics v4 API

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-api

I need to pass multiple date range to get response from GA.

As i provide 2 date range like this

```
dateRanges: [
                    {
                        startDate: "2018-09-01",
                        endDate: "2018-09-02"
                    },
                    {
                        startDate: "2018-09-03",
                        endDate: "2018-09-05"
                    }                  
                ],
```

I am getting response but when i add

```
dateRanges: [
                    {
                        startDate: "2018-09-01",
                        endDate: "2018-09-02"
                    },
                    {
                        startDate: "2018-09-03",
                        endDate: "2018-09-05"
                    },
                    {
                        startDate: "2018-09-06",
                        endDate: "2018-09-07"
                    }                    
                ],
```

My response is just null.

full request

```
 {  
   "resource":{  
      "reportRequests":[  
         {  
            "viewId":"149278594",
            "dateRanges":[  
               {  
                  "startDate":"2018-09-01",
                  "endDate":"2018-09-02"
               },
               {  
                  "startDate":"2018-09-03",
                  "endDate":"2018-09-05"
               },
               {  
                  "startDate":"2018-09-06",
                  "endDate":"2018-09-07"
               }
            ],
            "metrics":[  
               {  
                  "expression":"ga:users"
               }
            ],
            "dimensions":[  
               {  
                  "name":"ga:segment"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"ga:pagePath"
               }
            ],
            "dimensionFilterClauses":[  
               {  
                  "operator":"AND",
                  "filters":[  
                     {  
                        "dimensionName":"ga:pagePath",
                        "operator":"REGEXP",
                        "expressions":"^abc.com/.*"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "segments":[  
               {  
                  "segmentId":"gaid::2pK67nVBSVaAOb3P-9kEog"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am getting errorResponse

> "data":{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Request can have at most two
>   date ranges.","errors":[{"message":"Request can have at most two date
>   ranges.","domain":"global","reason":"badRequest"}],

Is there any way to achieve this (More than 2 date range )?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full request you are making so that we can test it.

Comment: @DaImTo updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"data":{  
   "error":{  
      "code":400,
      "message":"Request can have at most two date ranges.",
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "message":"Request can have at most two date ranges.",
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"badRequest"
         }
      ],
```

As the error message states you may have a max of two date ranges you have three remove one

```
            "dateRanges":[  
               {  
                  "startDate":"2018-09-01",
                  "endDate":"2018-09-02"
               },
               {  
                  "startDate":"2018-09-03",
                  "endDate":"2018-09-05"
               },
               {  
                  "startDate":"2018-09-06",
                  "endDate":"2018-09-07"
               }
            ],
```

Note: I have logged an error in the documentation [Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114277349)

Comment: There is a currently a backlog with regard to fixing the documetnation issues its on the log but it may take some time.